# addition by specific value of arithmetic values presented in file1 to file2

Tags: awk, arithmetic

I have in file 1 the following

```
'a 62-182'
'a 183-303'
'a 304-424'
...
```

is there any way I can have based on file1's value the following in file 2?

```
'a 62-182'  'a 7195-7315' 
'a 183-303' 'a 7316-7436' 
'a 304-424' 'a 7437-7557'
...
```

so adding an extra column which +7133 the arithmetic values in file 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This **awk** script takes the second field of the data and splits it into variables that can be used in a math operation:

```
$ cat data
'a 62-182'
'a 183-303'
'a 304-424'


$ awk '{ split($2,arr,"-");
  print $0"\t"$1, arr[1] + 7133 "-" arr[2] + 7133"\047" }' data
'a 62-182'  'a 7195-7315'
'a 183-303' 'a 7316-7436'
'a 304-424' 'a 7437-7557'
```

Comment: Many thanks! is there a way to preserve the single quotes and also then convert col 1 into a line which will then followed in the same line by col 2?

Comment: All in one line, like so?: `awk '{ split($2,arr,"-"); printf $0" "$1" "arr[1] + 7133"-"arr[2] + 7133"\047 " } END{print ""}' data`

Comment: ...or all one column? `awk '{ split($2,arr,"-"); print $0"\n"$1, arr[1] + 7133 "-" arr[2] + 7133"\047" }' data`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{gsub("-"," ",$0);print $1,$2"-"$3" "$1,$2+7133"-"$3+7133"'\''"}' filename
```

output

```
'a 62-182' 'a 7195-7315'
'a 183-303' 'a 7316-7436'
'a 304-424' 'a 7437-7557'
```

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
k=open ('p','r')
for i in k:
    d=i.strip().replace('-',' ').replace("'","").split(' ')
    print "'"+d[0]+" "+d[1]+"-"+d[2]+"'  "+"'"+d[0],str(int(d[1])+7133)+"-"+str(int(d[2])+7133)+"'"
```